# Converting HTML to PDF in Java not reading Forms values

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext

I'm trying to convert a html document into a PDF using java, and the only solution I found was using iText (XMLWorkerHelper).

It works, but my problem is that it seems to ignore HTML forms values, resulting in them not being showed in the final pdf. For instance, if I have a "Name: [Something written in a TextBox]" in my html,

```
<input class="layout" readonly="readonly" name="Name"
                  id="Name" value="ABCD WXYZ" size="83" maxlength="60"
                  type="text" />
```

only "Name: " will be in the pdf.

Any hint on how to solve this (stupid?) issue? Even using different (open source) APIs, of course.

My code attached:

```
private static void createPDF (){  

    String path = "myTest.pdf";  
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = null;  

    //create a new document  
    Document document = new Document();  

    try {  

     //get Instance of the PDFWriter  
     pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(path));  

     //document header attributes  

     //open document  
     document.open();  
     InputStream is = new FileInputStream("page.html");  

     // create new input stream reader  
     InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);  

     //get the XMLWorkerHelper Instance  
     XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();  
     //convert to PDF  
     worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, isr);  

     //close the document  
     document.close();  
     //close the writer  
     pdfWriter.close();  

    } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  

   }
```

As you can see there's not too much to compile, so I guess the problem is in the worker itself and maybe I'm ignoring something to make it work. If I try to convert the html page on any random online service, it works perfectly.

By the way, I tried to upload my html source to the iText demo (http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/) and it still has that problem...